# Unable to start scriptblock as background or remote job, works fine executing directly

Tags: powershell, invoke-command, start-job

I have a scriptblock I would like to run as a background job. Below is the command I would like to run:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse $source |  Get-DfsrFileHash | Export-csv -Append C:\Temp\Test_Source_Checksum.csv
```

If I run this command it goes through successfully with no issues.

I have tried the following for 'Start-Job'

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Get-ChildItem -Recurse $source |  Get-DfsrFileHash | Export-csv -Append C:\Temp\Test_Source_Checksum.csv }
```

This results in 'Get-Job' displaying as completed, when it actually hasnt, or doesnt appear to have judging by the missing file: 'Test_Source_Checksum.csv'

I have also tried using the following for 'Invoke-Command'

```
Invoke-Command -AsJob -ComputerName ($env:COMPUTERNAME) -ScriptBlock { Get-ChildItem -Recurse $source |  Get-DfsrFileHash | Export-csv -Append C:\Temp\Test_Source_Checksum.csv }
```

This results in 'Get-Job' displaying failed.

If I display the failure using:

```
(get-job -name Job38).JobStateInfo.Reason
```

I get nothing back...

Am I using Start-Job/Invoke-Command incorrectly here?

The reason I would like to run this as a background job is, im trying to copy large amounts of data and checksum it (for a DFS Migration). I would like to copy the data in smaller subsets, then checksum the data which has been copied whilst its copying the next batch over...rinse and repeat

Thanks,

Chris

EDIT:
Here is a copy of the whole script:

```
##----------------------------------------------------------------------------------##
$source="E:\DFSR_Migration_Test_Prod"
$dest="F:\DFSR_Migration_Test_Prod"
$what = @("/COPYALL","/B","/SEC","/E","/xd","dfsrprivate")
$options = @("/R:6","/tee","/MT:32")
$cmdArgs = @("$source","$dest",$what,$options)
##----------------------------------------------------------------------------------##
robocopy @cmdArgs
Write-Output "Prod_Copied @" (get-date) | Out-File C:\Temp\File_Copy.txt -Encoding ascii -Append -NoClobber
Write-Output "Initiating Prod Source Checksum @" (get-date) | Out-File C:\Temp\File_Copy.txt -Encoding ascii -Append -NoClobber
Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Get-ChildItem -Recurse $source | Get-DfsrFileHash | Export-csv C:\Temp\Prod_Source_Checksum.csv }
Write-Output "Initiating Prod Destination Checksum @" (get-date) | Out-File C:\Temp\File_Copy.txt -Encoding ascii -Append -NoClobber
Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Get-ChildItem -Recurse $dest | Get-DfsrFileHash | Export-csv C:\Temp\Prod_Destination_Checksum.csv }
```

Comment: Do you see any errors displayed if you try to receive the results from the job? `Get-Job | Receive-Job`

Comment: Yes I do, Thank you, it appears WinRM wasnt setup so couldnt run Invoke-Command. This is now resolved, but now, both Invoke-Command and Start-Job are the same, as in, they both say completed but have not executed the scriptblock (no 'Test_Source_Checksum.csv')

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you running? Have you tried to import the module within the scriptblock prior to running the Get-DfsrFileHash command?

Comment: Running version 5. Have just tried to add:
    `-InitializationScript {Import-Module DFSN,DFSR}`
But issue persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you passing $source? Because if you're doing nothing other than writing the variable name it'll be null, and if it's null you'll be executing Get-ChildItem for $pwd.Path on the remote system.

The simplest solution is to make $source into $using:Source.

```
Invoke-Command -AsJob -ComputerName ($env:COMPUTERNAME) -ScriptBlock { Get-ChildItem -Recurse $using:source |  Get-DfsrFileHash | Export-csv -Append C:\Temp\Test_Source_Checksum.csv }
```

Comment: $source is specified at the top of the script, i have updated the original post to include the whole script

Comment: $source declared at the top of the script won't be available inside Invoke-Command unless you use $using: to reference the local variable. Alternatively pass something in using ArgumentList (and either $args or declare a param block). If you had not used the -ComputerName parameter it would have been just fine.

Comment: Aha! thats exactly it, Chris, Thank you very much for your input! btw i did try without -Computername but added it as it was failing, but i guess this was due to WinRM not being setup correctly....lesson learned :) Thanks again

Comment: Ah sorry, you're using Start-Job. In that case you're stuck with ArgumentList. Variables declared outside of the script block are not available inside the job without more work. Remoting provides access with $using, there's no such mechanism for Start-Job. See: `$source = '123'; Start-Job { Write-Host $source } | Wait-Job | Receive-Job`

Comment: Im happy to use either really, just want to get the task done :) Your solution for Invoke-command has worked perfectly so ill use that

Comment: Extended Start-Job compatible example. `$source = '123'; Start-Job { param( $source ); Write-Host $source } -ArgumentList $source | Wait-Job | Receive-Job`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the good information above, remember that starting a job is a lot like opening a new console (that you cannot see directly), this means that you may need to re-connect or re-authenticate.  As an example, if you want to start a new job that uses PowerCLI, you will have to re-connect to your vCenter Server so in your scriptblock, you would preface your command with (connect-viserver...): `start-job -scriptblock {connect-viserver -server <vCenterServer>; powercli command}`.